# How to fake a validation error in a MonoRail controller unit-test?

Tags: unit-testing, validation, castle-monorail

I am running on Castle's trunk, and trying to unit-test a controller-action where validation of my DTO is set up.  The controller inherits from SmartDispatcherController.  The action and DTO look like:

```
[AccessibleThrough(Verb.Post)]
public void Register([DataBind(KeyReg, Validate = true)] UserRegisterDto dto)
{
    CancelView();
    if (HasValidationError(dto))
    {
        Flash[KeyReg] = dto;
        Errors = GetErrorSummary(dto);
        RedirectToAction(KeyIndex);
    }
    else
    {
        var user = new User { Email = dto.Email };
        // TODO: Need to associate User with an Owning Account
        membership.AddUser(user, dto.Password);
        RedirectToAction(KeyIndex);
    }
}

public class UserRegisterDto
{
    [ValidateNonEmpty]
    [ValidateLength(1, 100)]
    [ValidateEmail]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [ValidateSameAs("Email")]
    public string EmailConfirm { get; set; }

    [ValidateNonEmpty]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [ValidateSameAs("Password")]
    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }

    // TODO: validate is not empty Guid
    [ValidateNonEmpty]
    public string OwningAccountIdString { get; set; }

    public Guid OwningAccountId
    {
        get { return new Guid(OwningAccountIdString); }
    }

    [ValidateLength(0, 40)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [ValidateLength(0, 60)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The unit test looks like:

```
[Fact]
public void Register_ShouldPreventInValidRequest()
{
    PrepareController(home, ThorController.KeyPublic, ThorController.KeyHome, HomeController.KeyRegister);

    var dto = new UserRegisterDto { Email = "ff" };
    home.Register(dto);

    Assert.True(Response.WasRedirected);
    Assert.Contains("/public/home/index", Response.RedirectedTo);
    Assert.NotNull(home.Errors);
}
```

("home" is my HomeController instance in the test; home.Errors holds a reference to an ErrorSummary which should be put into the Flash when there's a validation error).

I am seeing the debugger think that dto has no validation error; it clearly should have several failures, the way the test runs.

I have read [Joey's blog post on this](http://joeydotnet.com/blog/archive/2007/10/25/monorail-controller-test-analysis---problem-and-resolution.aspx), but it looks like the Castle trunk has moved on since this was written.  Can someone shed some light, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.candland.net/blog/2008/07/09/WhatsNeededForCastleValidationToWork.aspx would appear to contain an answer.